# Why Facebook SDK Dashboards shows me conflicting data for iOS?

Tags: ios, facebook, ios9, facebook-sdk-4.x

I have followed every step in FBSDK iOS setup helper - including adding correct AppID to `*.plist`, activating an App with event in correct place etc. I have even tested my App by making test `Login` button. It worked correctly, homever on dashboard I became really confused. Although iOS section showed me `Last iOS Install - 6 seconds ago`, another section below showed me that `No installs were recorded in last 7 days`.[image]

And, last but not least - I tested it on fresh device - so it could be counted as `Organic Install`.
Did I miss anything? Glad to hear every idea.
BTW : On Android everythings works well and it says `1209 organic and paid installs were recorded in the last 7 days for Android.`

Comment: If I run the app on a iPhone simulator,will Organic Install be counted or not?